# UnsupportedOperationException in singleton Map

Tags: java, hashmap

When ever I try to run the following code it throws `UnsupportedOperationException`

However, as per my understanding it shoud work fine as I am computing value of `K` which is already present in `Map`

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collections.singletonMap("k", "v").computeIfAbsent("k", k -> "v" ); 
   }
}
```

Can some one help me understand this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Collections.singletonMap()` does not return a fully-implemented `Map`.

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> singletonMap(K key, V value) {
        return new SingletonMap<>(key, value);
}
```

Operations that try to update the map will throw `UnsupportedOperationException` (otherwise, the returned map is no longer immutable)

Answer (score 3):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap(K,%20V)) for that methods says:

> Returns an immutable map, mapping only the specified key to the specified value. The returned map is serializable.

Thus: no point in trying to *mutate* the map returned by that method.

Answer (score 0):

The Map Collections.singletonMap is immutable and doesn't support put(). Compute if absent puts the key and value into the map if its not present.

Use another Map type or just use get().

Answer (score 0):

> However, as per my understanding it should work fine as I am computing
>   value of K which is already present in Map

A `Map` instance created with `singletonMap()` doesn't allow indeed to add or remove entry in the map.
But immutability goes beyond. It implies that the whole state of the object cannot be changed. So it doesn't allow to update an existing entry (even with the same value as in your example) either as you tried :

```
Collections.singletonMap("k", "v").computeIfAbsent("k", k -> "v" );
```

In fact the only supported methods by a `SingletonMap` instance are retrieval methods : `get()`, `entrySet()` and so for... and any supported methods returning entries of the Map return a defensive copy of them as any immutable class should do.

Additionally, note that all `public static singletonXXX()` methods in `java.util.Collections` (`singleton()`, `singletonList()` and `singletonMap()` ) return immutable instances.